# pyaudioを用いて周波数スペクトルの表示

Tags: python

## 問題

pyaudioを用いて周波数スペクトルを表示させようとしたときに鳴らした音とずれた周波数が表示される

## ソースコード

```py
# 録音プロット部
import pyaudio
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import signal
import wave

# % matplotlib inline

input_device = 0
output_device = 1

def recording(CHANNELS, RATE, CHUNK, RECORD_SECONDS, FORMAT, p):
    print("録音中")
    stream = p.open(format=FORMAT,
                    channels=CHANNELS,
                    rate=RATE,
                    input=True,
                    input_device_index=input_device,
                    output_device_index=output_device,
                    frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)

    all = []
    for i in range(0, int(RATE / CHUNK * RECORD_SECONDS)):
        data = stream.read(CHUNK)
        all.append(data)
    stream.close()
    p.terminate()
    data = b''.join(all)
    print("終了")
    return data

if __name__ == '__main__':
    CHANNELS = 1
    RATE = 44100
    CHUNK = 2 ** 11
    RECORD_SECONDS = 3
    FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
    p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
    data = recording(CHANNELS, RATE, CHUNK, RECORD_SECONDS, FORMAT, p)

    x = np.frombuffer(data, dtype="int16") / 10000

    xs = (np.fft.fft(np.frombuffer(data, dtype="int16")))[:int(len(x) / 2)]

    # 振幅の絶対値をとる
    xr = np.abs(xs)

    # peak検出
    maxid = signal.argrelmax(xr, order=100)  # large peaks
    minid = signal.argrelmin(xr, order=100)  # small peaks

    # グラフプロット
    plt.figure(figsize=(13, 3))
    plt.axis

    plt.plot(maxid[0], xr[maxid[0]], 'rx', label='peak')
    plt.plot(minid[0], xr[minid[0]], 'bx', label='min peak')
    plt.plot(xr, label="beforeBPF")
    plt.xlim(0, 7000)  # Hz
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()
```

## 現状

普段音響の現場で使用しているアプリで1kHzの音を鳴らしたときに3kHzにピークが立ちました。
下の図がその時の出力結果です。
[image: 1kHzを鳴らしたときに表示されたグラフ]

Comment: 録音した結果は、ちゃんと1KHzの正弦波になっていますか？

Comment: 返信遅くなってしまい申し訳ございません
録音をwave形式で保存し再生したところ実際に1kHzの正弦波になっていました

Answer (score 0):

FFTを行った結果が何を表しているかわかっています？
int(fs/chunk*sec) = int(44100/2048*3) = 64
chunk * 64 = 131072 データをFFTにかければ、周波数分解能は 44100 / 131072 = 0.336 Hz でしょう。
3000番目のデータは 3000 * 0.336 で約1kHzで間違っていませんが？